# Are there any alternatives in clearing all columns of a DataGridView?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, winforms

I currently have this problem where the data in my DataGridView are disappearing yet they can be read in the DataBindings.

```
Public Sub FillDataSetAndView()

    SQL.ExecQuery("Select * From tblContestants")

    dgvContestants.DataSource = SQL.DBDT

    dgvContestants.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    dgvContestants.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill

    dgvContestants.Columns.Clear()

    dgvContestants.Columns.Add("ConName", "CONTESTANT NAME")
    dgvContestants.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "ConName"

    lblContName.DataBindings.Add("Text", SQL.DBDT, "ConName")
End Sub
```

The reason I used `dgvContestants.Columns.Clear()`is because I wanted to clear most of the columns reside in the `tblContetants(ConNum, ConName, ConImg)` and replace them with the only `column(ConName)` I want to load on the DataGridView.

The last line of codes is where I'll put the bindings to their place. The `ConImg` to the PictureBox and `ConNum` to value holder.

I know it's the `dgvContestants.Columns.Clear()` that made the data disappear since whenever I try to comment it out, the DataGridView shows the records just fine, but with all the unnecessary columns I want to disregard to the DataGridView.

Comment: You should wrap your dbName with QUOTENAME. As posted this is potentially vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange yes thank you for the reminder.

Comment: LOL I really meant to fix your query, not the  question. :D

Answer (score 0):

Assigning null to the datagridview DataSource is the best way to clear the databinds.

```
DataGrid.DataSource = Nothing
DataGrid.DataBind()
```